# Post request is not working in Angular 4 to a web Api service

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular4-httpclient

Code at Web API:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ODataRoute("UploadDartDetails")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadDartDetails([FromBody]CMM_DartBDO dartDetails)
        {
}
```

Trying to send the object CMM_DartBDO  from Angular side. Ia m using HttpClient module.

```
public postDARTData() { 
        this.dartDetails.dartId=1;
        this.dartDetails.documentVersionId=1;
        this.dartDetails.contactId=1;
this.postDartdetails(this.dartDetails).subscribe((SucessMessage)=> console.log('res'+SucessMessage));
}

postDartdetails(model: any)
        {
            return this.http.post('http://localhost:1148/CMMService-service/UploadDartDetails', model).map(res=>res.json());
        }
```

When it runs the service gets a hit and returns a proper response at its end but the angular code gets the error 406 (Not Authorized.)
Please help.

Comment: HTTP Status 406 is "Not Acceptable"

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a JSON object, use JSON.stringify

```
this.postDartdetails(JSON.stringify(this.dartDetails))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public postDARTData() { 
    this.dartDetails.dartId=1;
    this.dartDetails.documentVersionId=1;
    this.dartDetails.contactId=1;
    this.postDartdetails(this.dartDetails).subscribe(
        (res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.error);
            console.log(err.name);
            console.log(err.message);
            console.log(err.status);
        }
    );
}

postDartdetails(model: any) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:1148/CMMService-service/UploadDartDetails', model)
}
```